# removing labels in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, label

```
     temp_label = Label(text= str(temp) + 'C', pos=(-300, -50))
             temp_label.bind(on_touch_down = self.disappear)
             self.add_widget(temp_label)
    
    
   def disappear(self, label_instance, label_choice):
                self.remove_widget(self.temp_label)
```

I want to remove the label using  'on_touch_down' but everytime i do it i get this error

```
AttributeError: 'UK_Weather' object has no attribute 'temp_label'
```

Above is just a snippet of the code, if possible could the answer be in python language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing                                                                 ;

```
temp_label = Label(text= str(temp) + 'C', pos=(-300, -50))
             temp_label.bind(on_touch_down = self.disappear)
             self.add_widget(temp_label)
```

to:                                                             ;

```
self.temp_label = Label(text= str(temp) + 'C', pos=(-300, -50))
             self.temp_label.bind(on_touch_down = self.disappear)
             self.add_widget(self.temp_label)
```

Otherwise `self.temp_label` is not defined (as the error message says).